# Remove duplicate values in list box

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a list box and I bind it to my table Position and display the column Position. I inserted 2 values w/ the same position in my table and my list box displays 2 of the same values that i inserted. So, can you help me display only one of the same value in my list box?
i only have this code so far:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string select;


            select = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = this.mAINDATABASEDataSet.tblPosition.Select("Position like '%" + select + "%'");




            int numRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

            txtCount.Text = Convert.ToString(numRows);

            txtSearchCategory.Text = select.ToString();

            try
            {
                MAINDATABASEDataSet.tblCategorizationDataTable GetCategoryCommand1 = GetCategoryData(this.txtSearchCategory.Text.Trim());
                MAINDATABASEDataSet.tblCategorizationRow GetCategoryCommand2 = (MAINDATABASEDataSet.tblCategorizationRow)GetCategoryCommand1.Rows[0];

                this.txtSG.Text = GetCategoryCommand2.SalaryGrade.ToString();
                this.txtMales.Text = GetCategoryCommand2.Male.ToString();
                this.txtFemales.Text = GetCategoryCommand2.Female.ToString();

            }

            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This Position is not saved yet!", "Information".ToUpper(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                txtSG.Text = "";
                txtMales.Text = "";
                txtFemales.Text = "";
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            return;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Did you to do distinct while returning the results?

Comment: nope. i dont know what to do with this. i'm just a beginner. im sorry

Comment: Post your code. Let us see what you got so far.

Comment: i manually insert data in my tables. sorry, im too stupid on this.

Comment: how are you setting the datasource for listbox?

Comment: i use the databinding mode of the listbox. i didnt inserted any codes in the form load to databind my listbox

Comment: Then fetch the distinct records only from your table. it will look something like: SELECT distinct yourColumnName from yourTableName

Comment: i just did that one in search criteria builder of the listbox, it works but when i hit ok, it display's this message "The Schema returned by the new query differs from the base query"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by selecting distinct in LINQ. Try this for your data source:

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = this.mAINDATABASEDataSet
.GroupBy(i => i.Position)
.Select(i => i.First())
.Where(i => i.Position.Contains(select));
```

include `using System.Linq;` namespace in your project or reference it. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Can you tell what are you getting in datagridview1?